# want to convert 01:30 PM to 13:30

Tags: php, date, date-formatting

I work with PHP and I got time like 11:00 Am,1:00 PM. But I want to convert that time into 24 hours format.

example:

```
10:00 AM => 10:00
2:30 PM  => 14:30
```

Comment: *thanks in advance* We won't write your code! What have you tried?

Comment: i try with php date function but i did not get any solution

Comment: Then show us your attempts!

Comment: @Rizier123 this is small date conversation in this what i have to show ???? if u say i can show my controlle code

Comment: yes wait dear @coding cracker

Comment: @CodingCracker Maybe you want to read [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253833/3933332)

Comment: i dont use strtotime with date that is my mistake @rizier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
// 12-hour time to 24-hour time 
$time_in_24_hour_format  = date("H:i", strtotime("2:30 PM"));
```

Comment: i got variable data like 11:00 AM To 01:00 PM and do this $s_time = explode('To',$this->request->data['Appointment']['appointment_time_slot']);

Answer (score 2):

You can try using the `date` function like this:

```
date("H:i a", strtotime("10:00 AM"));
```

Comment: Depends on the user. I always want to have 'AM' or 'PM' even if it 's 24 hour format.

Answer (score 1):

Converting 12hour format to 24 hour format

[Convertion example](http://techblog2016.blogspot.in/2015/02/how-to-convert-12-hour-format-to-24.html)